# unset array key not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, unset

I am trying to get an associative aray from a form input, which works ok. But i dont want the new value to duplicate if the key already exist in the array. Here is how my $_POST function looks:

```
<?php // top of page
if ( isset( $_POST['drw_inventory'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['drw_inventory'],'update_drw_postmeta') )
{
      //if nonce check succeeds.
      global $post;
      $postid = $post->ID;
      $data = $_POST['wpd_function_rating'];
      $currentusr = wp_get_current_user();

      //Get the Existing user ratings of this post
      $ls_up_votes = (get_post_meta($postid, 'wpd_rating', TRUE ));

      //if the current user already rated, unset the rating
      foreach($ls_up_votes as $arr) {
          foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
              if (array_key_exists($currentusr->user_login, $arr)) {
                    unset($arr[$key]);
               }
          }
      }   
      //Add post meta 'wpd_rating' with this structure: 
      $ls_up_votes[] = array($currentusr->user_login => $data);
      update_post_meta($postid,'wpd_rating',$ls_up_votes);  
}
?>
```

The Form

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('update_drw_postmeta','drw_inventory'); ?>
   <label>This is label</label>
   <input type='text' name='wpd_function_rating' value='' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

This is how my array looks(you can see the duplicate user inputs, I want the array value to be updated on the existing username key):

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [user1] => 33 ) 
[1] => Array ( [user1] => 44 ) 
[2] => Array ( [user2] => 34 ) 
[2] => Array ( [user2] => 31 ) 
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either loop by reference, or unset from the bottom up `unset(($ls_up_vote[$whatever_the_key_of_arr_is][$key]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( $ls_up_votes as $k => $v ) {
    foreach ( $v as $k2 => $v2 ) {
        if ( array_key_exists($currentusr->user_login, $v) ) {
            unset($ls_up_votes[$k][$k2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. works great but its only removing the key and the value. is it possible to remove the empty arrays and re-sort the array numbers?
`Array ( 
[0] => Array () 
[1] => Array ( [user1] => 44 ) 
[2] => Array () 
[2] => Array ( [user2] => 31 ) 
)`